# How to display multiple error messages for the same attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where the user can add email addresses separated by a ','.

I process the emails in the controller:

```
        email_arr = extract_emails  
    email_arr.each do |email|
      unless @user.save 
      @email_err << email
      @user.add_email_errors
    end
```

In the User model:

def add_email_errors
      errors.add("#{email} is not a valid email address")
  end

On the form:

<%= error_messages_for :user %>

All this works fine except I am only getting the error message for the last email address.
So if a user enters the following:

bademail.com, notvalidemail.ca, etc on the form.

The error message is: "notvalidemail.ca is not a valid email address"

How can I get a list of all the invalid emails?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `save` resets the error table.

Comment: Thanks. I took out the @user.save and replaced it with @user.valid? I still just get the last bad email thought.

Comment: actually, more specifically, I think valid? resets it.  You may have to keep track of the errors in another variable and then add them at the end after the loop

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I guess that is the best way. I thought I could just keep adding them to the errors.add :email method and then get them all back on the form.